# TDateTimePicker is missing OnDblClick event with DELPHI XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tdatetimepicker

apologize if this question sounds somewhat stupid, but with XE2, i can see that the OnDblClick event of the TDateTimePicker seems to be missing from the list of events. 
Is it really the case? Here is how i proceed:

- I start a new VCL application
- instanciate a TDateTimePicker on the default Form

I can see from that the OnDblClick event is missing from the list of events of TDateTimePicker. 
On the other hand, with Delphi 7, it works fine and i can see the OnDblClick event. 
I did not manage to find any relevant information about that so far.

Is there some additional settings that one would need to do or am I simply missing some obvious step here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi 5-XE exposed the `OnDblClick` event in `TDateTimePicker`, but the event doesn't actually fire when you double-click on the DTP at runtime (I just tried it).  There is no `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLICK` message generated.

A bug report was filed in QualityCentral, but was closed "As Designed":

[#33027 TDateTimePicker.OnDblClick does not fire](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=33027)

The `OnDblClick` event was removed from `TDateTimePicker` in Delphi XE.